# Does anyone know the YM2410 pinout (from the PSS-130 and PSS-30 line of Yamaha keyboards)?

Tags: integrated-circuit, pinout, music

I was recently making modifications to a PSS-130 Keyboard, and before I knew it, the keyboard would cease to make noise. I have narrowed the issue down to the main chip on the PSS-130, the Yamaha YM2410. I have been trying to find the pinout for this chip but I have gotten no results on a pinout sheet from my searching. Does anyone have any knowledge about this chip, and even better, a pinout? Anything will help.

**This is the chip in question:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, well I couldn't find one, but did find a [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/1ccpm0/im_having_trouble_finding_a_datasheet_for_ic/) which says the YM2413 is a replacement. *That* was find-able.

It should be available shortly at https://octopart.com/ym2410-yamaha-20808295